# How to Turn Off the Path Hover in VSCode File Explorer?

Tags: ide, vs-code

The file path popup that appears when you hover over filenames in the VSCode File Explorer is my least favorite feature of VSCode. If I'm scrolling through a list of file names to find something, continual flickering popups competing for my attention while showing me the same path and repeating the file name are not enhancing usability. Does anyone know a way to make this behaviour stop or to substantially increase the delay?

[image: VSCode file explorer popup]

Comment: I would suggest posting this question in Stackoverflow instead of Salesforce Stackechange since more users might be answer this generic VSCode question.

Comment: Do you know that this is generic behavior for VSCode and not specific to the SF extension? I tried a few different searches and nothing came up about it.

Comment: VSCode has this file tree without the SF extensions so yes, it's generic

Comment: Thank you. I'l move it over when I get a spare moment.

Comment: Quick update. This issue has been reopened for VSCode.https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70768